# NixOS starting a daemon process example - is the example broken?

Tags: nixos, nix

In the python flask example application given on https://nixos.org/guides/dev-environment.html ... Isn't it just killing the daemon process whether it passes the health check or not? Maybe there's something implicit going on that I'm not grasping?

> You can also run a bash script like this one in your CI to make sure
> your default.nix keeps working in the future.

```
#!/usr/bin/env nix-shell
#! nix-shell -i bash
set -euo pipefail

# start myapp in background and save the process id
python myapp.py >> /dev/null 2>&1 &
pid=$!

# ok so we have the pid

if [[ $(curl --retry 3 --retry-delay 1 --retry-connrefused http://127.0.0.1:5000) == "Hello, Nix!" ]]; then
    echo "SUCCESS: myapp.py is serving the expected string"
    # and if the health check runs successfully, we kill the python process
    kill $pid
    exit 0
else
    echo "FAIL: myapp.py is not serving the expected string"
    # and if the health check fails, we kill the python process
    kill $pid
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

That example isn't about starting a daemon to be a long-running service, but about starting a daemon as a short-lived CI check, to ensure things should still work when someone does want to start the long-running daemon.